# Algorithm for get input(True) in raspberry and count its. similar old nokia mobile keyboard

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, gpio

Algorithm for get input(True) in raspberry and count its. similar old nokia mobile keyboard.

i was count how many receive True from GPIO raspberry in 1 of seconds?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're wanting to know how many times you receive a True signal within a one second window from a pre-configured GPIO pin. If that's the case I'd utilize time.clock() and a while loop:

```
import time

x = 0
start_time = time.clock()
end_time = start_time + 1

while (start_time < end_time):
    if (GPIO.input(17)):
        x = x + 1
    start_time = time.clock()

print(x)
```